# python : several cumprods per column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have the following df:

```
   id  column
   1   NaN
   1   1
   1   1.05
   1   1.10
   1   NaN
   1   NaN
   1   3
   1   1.08
   1   1.07
   1   NaN
```

I want to create a cumulative product over the column. However, the product should restart whenever NaN is in between. The result should look like this:

```
   id  column
   1   NaN
   1   1
   1   1.05
   1   1.155
   1   NaN
   1   NaN
   1   3
   1   3.24
   1   3.4668
   1   NaN
```

The following code seems ideal but it returns the error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'shift'.

```
df["column"] = df["column"].apply(lambda x: x*x.shift(1))
```

Also: This commands returns only zeros and treats the whole column as one product and thus seems not suitable for my problem:

```
df["column"] = df["column"].cumprod()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` with `cumsum` to identify groups to apply `cumprod` over:

```
df.groupby(df.column.isnull().cumsum()).cumprod()
```

Output:

```
   id  column
0   1     NaN
1   1  1.0000
2   1  1.0500
3   1  1.1550
4   1     NaN
5   1     NaN
6   1  3.0000
7   1  3.2400
8   1  3.4668
9   1     NaN
```